# Removing edges and splitting a connected component if necessary (C++, Boost)

Tags: c++, algorithm, boost, graph

I have a large graph (the number of vertices can be in the range of 50,000-100,000, the adjacency matrix need not be sparse). Edges in the graph can be removed/added, and I want to update the resulting connected components structure after such changes. I have implemented this in a straightforward fashion with a BFS search myself in C++ (keeping track of `unordered_map`s of vertices to connected component ids and updating them), but I am wondering if there is a more efficient way to do this using `Boost`'s graph library.

I was able to find some questions similar to this here in Stackoverflow, and came to know of `filtered_graph` (and the `connected_components` function) but I am worried about the overhead involved in creating such filtered instances, every time we add or remove an edge. (Or should this be a concern at all?!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe your solution is essentially the best possible. If you are only allowed to add edges, then I believe the algorithm can be improved by keeping track of connected components in terms of vertices included, and then when an edge is included you check to see if the two vertices belong to different connected components, in which case you merge the two connected components. This will reduce the complexity from quadratic to best-case per edge added. However, if you are allowed to insert and delete edges, I don't see any asymptotically faster way to solve the problem other that what you described.

Answer (score 2):

There are algorithms for maintaining connectivity under edge insertions and deletions that are faster than recalculating. This is called "dynamic graph connectivity". [Here](http://people.csail.mit.edu/rahul/papers/dyncon-jea2001.pdf) is a paper on experimental evaluations (some newer theoretical results have been found since, but it is unclear whether they have practical relevance).

Comment: Excellent! Thanks for the pointer to "dynamic connectivity". I am looking more into this.